# how to use custom CursorAdapter in SherlockListActivity?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-cursoradapter

My app uses ActionBarSherlock and I also need to use a Custom Cursor Adapter ? How can I do so as java doesn't allow multiple inheritance. That is :

`public class MyActivity extends SherlockListActivity,Cursor Adapter {}` is not allowed.

Comment: Make your cursor-adapter an extra class?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand clearly

Comment: Why not make a `MyCursorAdapter`-class, let it extend `CursorAdapter` and use it where you need it? Why would you want your Activity to also be a Adapter?

Comment: Besides what @LukasKnuth said, java doesn't allow multiple inheritance so you'll need an extra class for your adapter.

Comment: So its going to be `MyActivity extends SherlockListActivity` and `MyAdapter extends CursorAdapter` and i will use `MyAdapter` in `MyActivity` . I hope i got it right ?

Comment: That is correct; as the motto goes, "Favor composition over inheritance."